# Make expiring image or html

Tags: wordpress

I've built a wordpress site for artwork and would like to set it up so I can create a custom field in the admin that users can select and will display "new" on the front end. Creating this  is pretty simple but I would like to "new" to expire after thirty days. Any ideas on setting up the expiration part would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your "artwork" a custom post type, custom taxonomy, or perhaps just normal posts?

Comment: it is a custom post type "artwork" using the built in category

Comment: Are you needing to make "new" posts sort any differently than any other posts, or are you just needing (for example) to have different HTML/CSS display *while* they're "new" in their first 30 days?

Comment: just want the html/css "new" to expire 30 days after it is checked and disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you currently have a custom post type archive template (by default, if your custom post type is named "artwork" it would be `archive-artwork.php`, you could create a check for the date it was published using [`the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) function like so:

```
// expiration date is a rolling date from 30 days ago
$expiration_date = date('Ymd', strtotime("-30 days"));

// use the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo ) to get the current post's
// date in the loop
$post_date = the_date('Ymd', '', '', false);

// compare the dates and output different markup or classes to your HTML
if ($post_date < $expiration_date) {
    echo '<div class="expired-post">';
}
else {
    echo '<div class="new-post">';
}
```

Comment: That worked great. I'm outside the loop so i had to use `get_the_time('Ymd', $post->ID);` thanks